# xcodebuild command tool without installing Xcode itself

Tags: xcode, command-line, xcodebuild

I need to build a Xcode project in an automated process on a machine that will not be making any development. I also want to save disk space on that machine.

I thought the `xcodebuild` command line would be perfect for that. But to install that tool, you need to install Xcode itself. Is there a way to install only `xcodebuild` and other dependencies?

I tried to install [this package](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer), it does include `xcodebuild`, but other dependencies seems missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that Apple has a CLI only install, that's probably the best way to go.

Old answer below.

---

You need some files missing.

- Install [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) to install GCC and LLVM
- Copy these files from an existing Xcode installation or from the installer :

  - Everything in `/Developer/Library/`
  - Everything in `/Developer/usr/`
  - The platform you need (iOS or MacOSX) in `/Developer/Platforms/`
  - The SDK your building against in `/Developer/SDKs/`

That's it! Enjoy your minimalist Xcode install.

Comment: I found that I also needed to explicitly specify `DEVELOPER_DIR=/Library/Developer`, otherwise `xcodebuild` wouldn't know what files to use.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT install osx-gcc-installer as @gcamp suggested.

I did, and it corrupted my system files to an extent that I had to reinstall OSX.

This is how you uninstall osx-gcc-installer completely, and restore your system files:
http://magnemg.tumblr.com/post/113251602430/how-to-completely-uninstall-osx-gcc-installer

You probably need to install Xcode (I did, when having to upgrade to Qt 5, which had a hard dependency on Xcode. There was no way around it.). Or you might be lucky and can get away with just installing the official Apple CLT:

> Apple now provides an official Command Line Tools for Xcode package
>   that you can install without needing to install Xcode itself! You can
>   download it from [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (free registration required)
>   and search for "Command Line Tools".

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20671590/380607 which says:

> It appears that OSX has changed xcodebuild to require XCode to be
>   installed, where before it functioned properly with only the OSX
>   Command Line Tools installed.

Comment: Yeah, that answer is pretty old, and a lot of things have changed in the Xcode/xcodebuild land. Will edit my answer.