# pyobjc installation failure: xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, python-2.7, pip, pyobjc

I need `pyobcj` in order to have `pyttsx` work. When I attempt to install pyobjc with pip, I get the following:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:WebForm $MyName$ sudo pip install pyobjc
The directory '/Users/$MyName/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 7.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The directory '/Users/$MyName/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pyobjc
  Downloading pyobjc-3.0.4.tar.gz
Collecting py2app>=0.8 (from pyobjc)
  Downloading py2app-0.9.tar.gz (1.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.7MB 137kB/s 
Collecting pyobjc-core==3.0.4 (from pyobjc)
  Downloading pyobjc-core-3.0.4.tar.gz (2.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.2MB 103kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info
    writing include/pyobjc-compat.h to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/include/pyobjc-compat.h
    writing include/pyobjc-api.h to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/include/pyobjc-api.h
    writing pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing namespace_packages to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/pyobjc_core.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-4NP01v/pyobjc-core/setup.py", line 619, in <module>
        **parse_package_metadata()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-4NP01v/pyobjc-core/setup.py", line 331, in run
        egg_info.egg_info.run(self)
      File "<string>", line 15, in replacement_run
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 207, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 291, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 320, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 130, in add_defaults
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-4NP01v/pyobjc-core/setup.py", line 471, in finalize_options
        universal_newlines=True).strip()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/xcodebuild', '-version', '-sdk', 'macosx', 'Path']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-4NP01v/pyobjc-core
```

I've retried using the suggested `-H` flag, with no luck. What am I missing here?

- Python: 2.7.10
- OS: X, Yosemite

Comment: Do you have command line tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode is a [requirement](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html#requirements), so [install](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) it and the *Command Lines Tools* via your preferred shell:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I get the same error.
I already have the command line tools installed, `xcode-select --insall`yields `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`. Do I really need a full XCode installation?

Comment: Verify that you’ve successfully installed Xcode Command Line Tools `xcode-select -p` and the compiler `gcc --version`.

Comment: Yeah, this works. I just only have the command line tools but no complete Xcode installation, and that seems to be a problem (since El Capitan or so): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20671590/2148890