# Development Platform using PhoneGap on a Mac Pro

Tags: ios, node.js, git, cordova

I am setting up a development platform using my Mac Pro. I have installed `GIT`, `NODEJS`, `PhoneGap` and `Cordova`. I have cloned a repository to my computer successfully and added the IOS platform. But when I go to build my project I get an error:
`Command failed with exit code 2.`

Is there something else I need to install?

here is my error:

> bash-3.2# sudo -s 
>   bash-3.2# phonegap build ios 
>   [phonegap] executing
>   'cordova build ios'... Running command:
>   /Users/developer/PhoneBook/DOR_Phonebook_mobile/DorPhonebook/platforms/ios/cordova/build
>
> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active
>   developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
>   line tools instance
>
> ERROR building one of the platforms: Error:
>   /Users/developer/PhoneBook/DOR_Phonebook_mobile/DorPhonebook/platforms/ios/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 2 You may not have the required
>   environment or OS to build this project
>
> Error:
>   /Users/developer/PhoneBook/DOR_Phonebook_mobile/DorPhonebook/platforms/ios/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

Comment: do u have xcode and cli tools installed?

Answer (score 0):

First off all, you don't need Cordova **and** PhoneGap because you just install the same thing with another name.

After you choosed the name which sounds better for you, you should solve your XCode Problem. There is already a question here on Stackoverflow -> [Unable to use xcode-commandlinetools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605862/unable-to-use-xcodebuild-on-mavericks-with-command-line-tools-installed).

As i can see it over there, i first would recommend you to check whether you have installed the latest version of xcode and node. If you already have the latest version, try to re-install Xcode or try to run

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

After you did all like i said try to create a project again.